# NodeJs express, not caching images

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to download images from a some websites and then present them for my users.

Everything work excepts that the browser dose not cach tha image and send request every time to the server.

I dont understand what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code please have a look

```js
app.get("/api/imageHandler", jsonParser, async(reg, res) => {
  try {
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=345600'); // 4 days
    res.setHeader('Expires', new Date(Date.now() + 345600000).toUTCString());
    res.setHeader('Last-Modified', "Mon, 03 Jan 2011 17:45:57 GMT");
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');



    var url = decodeURIComponent(client.descriptString(reg.query.url.replace(/.jpg/g, ""))); // decrypt the image url
    addCore(res, false);

    console.log(res.statusCode)
    let headers = {
      "Cache-Control": "max-age=3600",
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
      referer: url,
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36',
    };

    var data = await fetch(url, {
      headers: headers,
      method: 'GET',
    });
    var buffer = Buffer.from(await data.arrayBuffer(), "binary")
    res.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', buffer.length); // How many bytes we're going to send
    res.send(buffer);
    res.end();

    //
  } catch (e) {
    res.statusCode = (403);
    res.end("not found")
    console.log("ImageHandler.Error", e, reg.query.url);
  }
});
```

Devtools network

```js
//Reponse header
Request URL: http://localhost:51189/api/imageHandler?url=%C2%A4U2FsdGVkX1%2BYZdlsFGcmb1ruO4vIpBLIWBfCznvdFkOnfCVL527%2BU2DGI3jVj7FAOF9pfw9to9k5woHLl%2BMGkrt27R9FfNNmQYPEbIfRK6L6lwrHCa%2BOQ%2BYDJXXskAcLd%2BNYIBIXdcT9XXVYOXqZPA%3D%3D.jpg
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:51189
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
age: 345600
Cache-Control: public, max-age=345600
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 13822
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Fri, 07 Jan 2022 16:03:41 GMT
Expires: Tue, 11 Jan 2022 16:03:41 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Last-Modified: Mon, 03 Jan 2011 17:45:57 GMT
Max-Age: 345600
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,sv;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:51189
Referer: http://localhost:3006/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: image
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664




// request header

Accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,sv;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:51189
Referer: http://localhost:3006/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: image
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

Your case is impossible to cache.
When loading the image for the second time, the browser will send a request with:

```
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 03 Jan 2011 17:45:57 GMT
If-None-Match: dc63-CDESmvxiYp5gyK/YZMkKANMfsX8
```

However Express won't be able to decide whether this is true or not, since it must run your callback to know what you are going to send.

Only `express.static()` and `res.sendfile()` can do what you want since in this case Express can examine the file before starting to answer.

If you want caching in your case, you should implement it yourself, look at this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fresh

PS: No, in fact, Express does send a `304 Not modified`, my bad - since it examines the data you sent - but it still cannot decide this without running your callback

Comment: nice, will surly take a look at the fresh library and see if it work.

Comment: tested this and it dose not work. ` res.getHeader('etag')` always undefined even though i see it in the web being send

Comment: `etag` won't be there until you set it - that's why you need to implement this yourself - Express is already doing what's in the example
This means check the `If-None-Match` header and download the image only if you need to

Comment: Yes and how do I do that ? could you give an example

Comment: What do you want to cache? In your case you can simply base your caching on the `if-modified-since`
Most naive implementation:
`if (req.getHeader(''If-Modified-Since')) {
    res.statusCode = 304
    res.end()
    return
}`

Better: check the date

Comment: The problems is that I am not getting `if-modified-since` or `etag` in the response.

Comment: You need to check in the request, there won't be anything in the response until you have responded and then it would too late.

In the very beginning in your callback check for `reg.get('If-Modified-Since')` - if it is set, respond with a 304. You don't need `fresh` for this.

Comment: Nope not getting `If-Modified-Since` is null, even reg.fresh is false

Comment: I noticed something when I browse to the image directly, it work but when I load in my app as `<img src` it dose not work

Comment: Check the browser headers, you can see them in Chrome DevTools in the the network tab

Comment: I added the headers above please have a look

Comment: These headers are not produced by the same code as before - `LastModified` and `etag` are missing now - this is why the browser does not even try to cache it now

Comment: I removed etag and only have `Last-Modified` its there in response

Comment: Won't work without it - this is part of the browser decision - the browser decides if it is sending `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match`. Then Node.js/Express decides to answer with a `304 Not modified` - if your callback has this check it in the beginning

Comment: added it and still not working

Comment: Check if the browser sends everything. The exchange is first request - Express sends `etag` and `Last-Modified` in the response, second request the browser sends `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match` in the request and then your callback sends `304 Not modified` without a response. All of these must be present.